The exact reason why a formula is orthogonal invariant under the sphere integral
Define
\begin{equation*}
  I(e)=\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}|e\cdot \omega|\,\mathrm{d}S(\omega),\quad e\in \mathbb{S}^{n-1},
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $n\geqslant 2$ is the sphere of the unit ball and $e\cdot \omega$ stands the inner product of $e$ and $\omega$. Then $I(e)$ is orthogonal invariant. Indeed, Let $T$ be an arbitrary orthogonal matrix. Then
\begin{align*}
  I(Te)
  &=\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} |Te\cdot \omega|\,\mathrm{d}S(\omega)\\
  &=\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} |e\cdot T^\mathrm{T}\omega|\,\mathrm{d}S(\omega).
\end{align*}
Let $\eta=T^\mathrm{T}\omega$, then $\omega=T\eta$. Hence
\begin{align*}
    I(Te)
    &=\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} |e\cdot \eta| \,\mathrm{d}S(T\eta)
     =\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} |e\cdot \eta| \,\mathrm{d}S(\eta)
     =I(e).
\end{align*}
My question is, I do not know exactly why $\mathrm{d}S(T\eta)=\mathrm{d}S(\eta)$. But if the sphere integral $\mathrm{d}S(T\eta)$ is replaced by the usual integral $\mathrm{d}(T\eta)$, I am sure that
\begin{equation*}
  \mathrm{d}(T\eta)=|T|\mathrm{d}\eta=\mathrm{d}\eta.
\end{equation*}
So could you provide me with more details? Thank you!

the question of how you justify invariance of the spherical measure under orthogonal maps depends on how exactly you define the measure. But a general enough change of variables theorem can be found in my answer here. Now, since orthogonal maps are isometries of the Riemannian metric induced on $\Bbb{S}^{n-1}$, the result trivially follows.

@peek-a-boo OK. Thank you!
